# Remove data using regex

Tags: regex

I have below mentioned data

```
E-mail: toch.bonboramy@acledabank.com.khMr. SOM Manil, Senior Assistant Vice President & Assistant Branch ManagerE-mail: som.manil@acledabank.com.khMr. LEE Chanvathana, Assistant Vice President & Manager of Marketing OfficerE-mail: lee.chanvathana@acledabank.com.khVillage 7, Sangkat Kampong Leav, Krong Prey Veng, Prey Veng Province, Cambodia.SWIFT Code: ACLBKHPPAnd 5 branches:
```

Where I need to remove the E-mail: toch.bonboramy@acledabank.com.khMr., the E-mail would remain constant and rest of the data would change. I am trying to remove the same using regex

```
E-mail: getemail\('([^']*)','[^']*'\)([^@]*@\1)
```

It gets removed when E-mail content has getmail in it. Can anyone help here please.

Comment: could u please provide the expected output?

Comment: What's wrong with your previous question? Why you used `getemail` string  in your regex?

Comment: i think @nhahdth provided this `E-mail: getemail\('([^']*)','[^']*'\)([^@]*@\1)` regex. You could ask any questions regarding the regex provided to him.

Answer (score 0):

```
E-mail:\s\S+\.
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/19